# EF6: Order by using anonymous type + Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to execute the following query with EF6:

```
var contracts = ctx.Orders
        .Include(c => c.OrderLines)
        .Where(c => c.IdCompany == idCompany)
        .OrderBy(x => new {OrderByColumn}) //OrderByColumn is a string
        .ToPagedQuery(pageSize, pageNumber) //ordinary Skip and Take
        .ToList();
```

but it throws this SqlException:

```
A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.
```

The problem happens when I use Include together with the anonymous type in the OrderBy clause.

I know that anonymous types don't work well with Include on projections ([Projecting to an Anonymous Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx#ProjectToAnonymousType)), but I don't know if this applies to OrderBy clauses.

Is there a way of doing that? If not, why it doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Why are you trying to order by an instance of an anonymous type that has nothing to do with your data?

Comment: I think he's trying to order by a column by name.  If `OrderByColumn == "thiscolumn"` then `.OrderBy(x => x.thiscolumn)` sort of thing.  Is that right, peflorencio?

Comment: Ops! Sorry. That semicolon doesn't exist in the original code. @Amy: Yes, I am trying to order by a column name. I have found some extension methods for that

Comment: So... You have Orders entities which have a well defined stucture... Isn't that OrderByColumn in your entity already?

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea: Yes, but the OrderBy column is defined dinamically.

Comment: TBH, that looks more like a hack. You could still build the linq query, but without the .OrderBy and ToList. Then have a switch append the correct .OrderBy clause to the query and then, finally, call ToList() on it.

Comment: @MihaiCaracostea: I don't see it as a hack. I could use a switch, but this is not the only query that I want to order dinamically and there are almost 70 columns (not my fault) to choose from in this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an extension method that receives a string instead of an anonymous type ([dynamic-linq-orderby-using-string-names](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b85ed9a-f3f4-41a0-bc9f-02c868539746/dynamic-linq-orderby-using-string-names?forum=adodotnetentityframework)). Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think your order by part should be like this:

```
.OrderBy(x => x.OrderByColumn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mix projection and sort.
Orderby doesnt not expect an anonymous type. The Select Can use an anonymous type

```
  // context DbSet.....
   .Where(w=>w.Id == "return true")  // an expression that returns true
   .OrderBy(o=>o.Name)        // expression that returns a prop Name not anonymous type 
   .Select(s=> new {s.Id, s.Name});  // New type with 2 fields
```

The Orderby Signature

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this    IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
```

The Select Signature

```
 public static IQueryable<TResult> Select<TSource,TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector)
```